# Lists.asmx truncates data

Tags: list, web-services

I have a custom Site page that contains some javascript code (using jquery and `SPServices`), that calls `Lists.asmx` Web service to perform CRUD operations on the list. At the init, my js code needs all list items. Recently I notided, that the latest added list items are not returned. Using Fiddler, I investigated that they are not simply included in the result set.
As older items seem to be useless for my code, there's a simply solution just to clear them.
But the question still remains, if the `Lists.asmx` has any limit of the items to return, and if it has how to configure it.
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using [Lists.GetListItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvclists.lists.getlistitems.aspx) to get the list items.

In the call the `rowLimit` specifies how may items you maximum want returned. If it's not specified, then the rowLimit is taken from the view with the Id specified in `viewName`, if that isn't specified then from the default view.

The `query` parameter can be used to limit the selection based on a CAML query (see the answer from @JohnChapman) and can also specify the order, so you get the newest items first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the number of results in the CAML query sent to the Lists web service.  SharePoint Magazine had a good article about using CAML queries against the web service: http://sharepointmagazine.net/articles/writing-caml-queries-for-retrieving-list-items-from-a-sharepoint-list.  In addition, the MSDN documentation on the CAML query schema might be helpful for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms467521.aspx.